# How to model whether a value is the original value or an amended value?

Tags: database, database-design, uml, database-schema

I will create an application for management, and i have some issues with modeling the database.

I have this case : 

- the organization has some services to sell (modeled with table 'prestation').

- the organization has clients (modeled with table 'client'). 

- a client has contracts and a contract may be having amendments to the contract (contact is the 'contrat' and amendment is 'avenant' in the schema).

When a client has signed a contract, he has services related to that contract.(that i modeled with 'prestclient').

Each service has its price related to a contract.

My problem is, when the price changes due to an amendment, I can't tell from the table 'prestclient' whether the price is the original price from the contract or due to the amendment of that contract.

So my question is : How can I modify my schema to have this information ?

Note that the amendement of a contract can only modify a subset of the services of that contract, so for some services, the prices cannot change. I must know whether the price is the one of the initial contract or not.

Here is my model (as beginner) :

[image: My MCD]

Comment: Google for "Database Historization" and you will see that this is a very broad and complex matter. A changing price can have many reasons and effects. Your requirements are not clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to know whether the price is original or amended, you can add a boolean column to prestclient 'isOriginal'.

If you want to know exactly which amendments are involved, you need to do more.
I assume an amendment can update multiple prices and a price can be amended by multiple amendments. In that case, you could add a table prestclient_Avenant related to prestclient and Avenant to record which amendments amended which prices. If an amendment can only update one price, you could add columns to Avenant telling which price of which service was amended by that amendment.